# Difference between std::string's operator[] and const operator[]

Tags: c++, operators

Can anyone please explain the difference between:

```
const char& operator[] const
```

and

```
char& operator[]
```

in C++?
Is it true that the second one is duplicating the string? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both return references to the internal member of the string.

The first method is defined as a const method (the last const) and as such promises not to change any members. To make sure you can;t change the internal member via the returned reference this is also const.

```
  const char& operator[](int i) const
//                              ^^^^^ this means the method will not change the state
//                                    of the string.

//^^^^^^^^^^^  This means the object returned refers to an internal member of
//             the object. To make sure you can't change the state of the string
//             it is a constant reference.
```

This allows you to read members from the string:

```
std::string const  st("Plop is here");

char x  = st[2];          // Valid to read gets 'o'
st[1]   = 'o';            // Will fail to compile.
```

For the second version it say we return a reference to an internal member. Neither promise that the object will not be altered. So you can alter the string via the reference.

```
   char& operator[](int i)
// ^^^^^  Returns a reference to an internal member.

std::string mu("Hi there Pan");

char y = mu[1];           // Valid to read gets 'i'
mu[9]  ='M';              // Valid to modify the object.
std::cout << mu << "\n";  // Prints Hi there Man
```

> Is it true that the second one is duplicating the string? and why?

No. Because it does not.

Answer (score 5):

No, the second returns a non-constant reference to a single character in a string, so you can actually use it to alter the string itself (the string object is not duplicated at all, but its contents are possibly modified).

```
std::string s = "Hell";
s[0] = 'B';

// s is "Bell" now
```

Given this sample, `char& operator[]` can of course be used to access a single character without modifying it, such as in `std::cout<< s[0];`.

However, the `const` overload is needed because you cannot call non-const member functions on const objects. Take this:

```
const std::string s = "Hell";
// ok, s is const, we cannot change it - but we still expect it to be accessible
std::cout << s[0];

// this, however, won't work, cannot modify a const char&
// s[0] = 'B';
```

Generally, the compiler will pick the `const` overload only when being called on a const object, otherwise it will always prefer to use the non-const method.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with const-correctness. Allowing read-only access in a const string and allowing writable access in a mutable string require two methods.

The `const char& operator[] const` accessor is necessary if you want to access a character from a `const std::string`. The `char& operator[]` accessor is necessary to modify a character in a `std::string`.

Comment: +1, *The issue is with const-correctness* If you let it, C++ provides some powerful aids that keep you and others from shooting yourself in your foot (or even higher).

Answer (score 1):

The second one does not need to duplicate (copy) the string.  It just returns a reference to a character which is modifiable.  The first one returns a non-modifiable reference, because it has to: the function itself is const, meaning it can't mutate the state of the string.

Now, if you have copy-on-write strings (an optimization employed sometimes), then getting a non-const reference to a piece of the string may imply copying (because the reference implies writing).  This may or may not be happening on your particular platform (which you didn't specify).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I thought that copy-on-write implementations are effectively disallowed now that both `operator[]` must have constant time complexity?

Comment: That may or may not be, but just because they are not supported by the standard doesn't mean people don't implement them.  :)

Comment: @Charles: I don't believe COW is disallowed in 03, just in 11. But nobody still used it for standard library implementations, so the distinction is a minor one.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: Just for clarification, I was talking about C++11. After all, C++03 has now been withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Some Basics :

```
With operator[] you can both edit value in a container/memory and read value.
```

With `const char& operator[] const` you are only allowed to read value.
Eg.

`std::string ss("text");
char a = ss[1];`

with `char& operator[]` you can edit the value. Eg


`ss[1] = 'A';`